# Can't convert HTMLImageElement to string?

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to reach img elements nested in some `<div>`.After that I want to add those images to a string variable.

I wrote that:

```
var SomeVariable="";
$("myDivId img").each(function(){
  console.log(this);
  SomeVariable += this;
});
console.log(SomeVariable);
```

When *`console.log`* is used in `.each` function, it shows something like:

`<img (some elements)>`, which is exactly what I want.

When I use *`console.log`* at the end, to write whole value, it says:

```
[object HTMLImageElement][object HTMLImageElement]
```

I tried to use some conversion, but I don't really know how to get to it.

Comment: Do you want the string representation of their HTML?

Comment: DOM elements are not HTML. The console just *represents* them with HTML syntax for visual purposes. The correct `toString()` value of the element is `[object HTMLImageElement]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want the string representation of their HTML...

```
var html = $("myDivId img").clone().appendTo("<div />").html();
```

If you're only supporting browsers which have the `outerHTML` property.

```
var html = $("myDivId img")
           .map(function() { return this.outerHTML; }).get().join("");
```

The reason you get `"[object HTMLImageElement]"` is because an [`Object`'s `toString()`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.2) will give you `"[object x]"`, where `x` is the `[[Class]]` (an internal property) of the object.

Comment: I need to get the string representation of their html, but I need to do it in the .each() function. I don't know how to use Your suggestion in .each() :(

Comment: @KamilT Mine doesn't use `each()`, it uses `map()`.

Comment: I think in your first solution, the `.appendTo(...)` will  return the `.clone()`'d elements instead of the new `div`, so you'll need `.parent()` before `.html()`.